# Excel - Group Rows together Sequentially

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I am working with a dataset of around 2000 rows.

The rows can have multiples of the same account but different charges. (For example, Account 3745 shows up 3 times with charges $1000, $500, and $250)

I want to have a column that will sequentially label the account with numbers 1-3; 1 being the account with the largest charge, 2 being the next largest, and 3 being the lowest.(Example: 1 - $1000, 2 - $500, - 3 - $250)

Then the next grouping of accounts will have it's own sequential numbering 1-x number, doing the same thing as above.

Is there a formula for this or do I have to get fancy somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,A2,$B$2:$B$10,">"&B2)+1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use `countif()` for this

if your account data is in column A adding a column with a formula like below and copy to all rows

```
=countif(A$1:A1,A1)
```

so on row 2 it would read

```
=countif(A$1:A2,A2)
```

Comment: Thank you! That does solve the sequential problem. Now it's a matter of setting each number to the charge amount, highest to lowest. Highest to lowest.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365 you can make use of `SORTBY`.

If your data is in `A1:B10`, where `A1:A10` is the Account and `B1:B10` is the Charges then use:
`SORTBY(A1:B10,A1:A10,1,NA:B10,-1)`

This will sort your data on Account ascending and on Charges descending.